# flex printing, fit to page

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am using `<mx:PrintDataGrid/>` to print multipage datagrid in flex. Its working but not fitting all the columns in the page - but rather just taking the hard coded width of columns from the datagrid.

I tried MATCH_WIDTH but no use...

```
var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
printJob.addObject(thePrintView,FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH)
```

I want all the columns to shrink corresponding their original width in datagrid and fit into page while printing. Is this even possible in Flex printing? if yes, then how to accomplish that? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No one? I could generate the pdf using alive pdf very well. But could someone guide as how to fit all columns in one page in Flex printing.

Comment: try changing printer setting to landscape style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I completed it by writing lot of custom code (getting page width and then dynamically setting the datagird's columns' width in percents)...